# FSCalendar 'didSelect'-Event fires too late?

Tags: swift, events, calendar, click, fscalendar

Hope u had a great day so far...

I am trying to build a Calendar app in Swift iOS using the `FSCalendar` library and that works quite good. Now in a dictionary I saved dates and the matching data for this date, so that's what I call now an Event in this post.

And I try to show the data in a label, when the user clicks on the date matching to the data in the dictionary. 
For that I made the appDelegate, like described on the cocoa pods-FSCalendar Homepage...

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {

    let dateString = stringFromDate(date as Date)

    print(dateString)
    print(dateprotocol.keys.contains(dateString))

    if(dateprotocol.keys.contains(dateString)){
        calendarlabel.text = dateprotocol[dateString]
    }

}
```

So I know the events are not the same 100%, but there is no such. an event called 'didSelectDate' like on https://cocoapods.org/pods/FSCalendar and when I manually type that, the event won't fire.

Otherwise in my Code-Example it fires too late, so when I choose the date where the Event is the data will be displayed, only when I select a different date after I clicked that date with data... Any Ideas why or how I can fix that? Maybe call some other date programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are doing this in `didDeselect date` delegate function instead of `didSelect date`. That explains why the event fires at the next selection :-)

If you're saying that `didSelect` function doesn't appear in your suggestions when you're trying to include it, **make sure if your ViewController is confirmed to`FSCalendarDelegate` and `FSCalendarDataSource`** like below and **use the `didSelect` function** instead of yours:

```
extension YourViewController: FSCalendarDelegate,FSCalendarDataSource {

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
       // Do the same inside this function and you should be fine

       let dateString = stringFromDate(date as Date)

       print(dateString)
       print(dateprotocol.keys.contains(dateString))

       if(dateprotocol.keys.contains(dateString)){
          calendarlabel.text = dateprotocol[dateString]
       }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, have a good one!

Comment: I so dumb ... Thank u :D

Comment: If this helped, consider an upvote and accepting the answer. Happy to help! Also, this happens to everyone at times, so please don't feel embarrassed ;-)